# How To debug and fix a PPTP VPN client connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm trying to set up a VPN client. I have configured it with the same settings I use on a Mac and I am able to connect from that without any problem.

When I click on the VPN connections I see two messages pop up, one after the other.

1) VPN connection has been successfully established

2) The VPN connection failed.

I've searched around for a solution without any luck. I'm not experienced in these matters at all. I've provided the log in the hope that it helps.

```
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 3052
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> VPN connection 'Bioxydyn' (Connect) reply received.
pppd[3056]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
pppd[3056]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
pppd[3056]: Using interface ppp0
pppd[3056]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
NetworkManager[2650]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
NetworkManager[2650]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
NetworkManager[2650]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
pptp[3060]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
whoopsie[996]: online
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
whoopsie[996]: online
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 10009).
whoopsie[996]: online
pppd[3056]: CHAP authentication succeeded
pppd[3056]: LCP terminated by peer
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:929]: Call disconnect notification received (call id 10009)
whoopsie[996]: online
whoopsie[996]: online
pppd[3056]: Connection terminated.
avahi-daemon[630]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
NetworkManager[2650]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
NetworkManager[2650]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
pppd[3056]: Modem hangup
pptp[3060]: nm-pptp-service-3052 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
pptp[3060]: nm-pptp-service-3052 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
NetworkManager[2650]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
pppd[3056]: Exit.
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
pptp[3074]: nm-pptp-service-3052 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
NetworkManager[2650]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> Policy set 'virginmedia2204860' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
NetworkManager[2650]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
NetworkManager[2650]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you connect to vpn server with chap auth, and after that

pppd[3056]: LCP terminated by peer

Try to switch off MPPE encryption.